# Cannot access all classes from tailwindcss

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwindcss and I just installed it to see how it looks.

I installed vue with `npm init vue@latest`

Then I installed Tailwindcss following the [documentation with postcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)

It works fine, I also tried to import something from Tailwindui and I can see that it use the correct styling.

Unfortunately, when I started to play with some classes, in my case with the `bg-` classes, I noticed that only a few are available.

I tried to use `bg-red`, `bg-zinc`, etc... and nothing worked. It looks like I can only use `bg-indigo-100` and `bg-indigo-600`.

I didn't change or update the default tailwind configuration and I cannot find anything in the documentation that mention how to allow loading the whole css.

This is the current `tailwind.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */ 
module.exports = {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {},
  plugins: []
}
```

I hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: Tailwind by default doesn't has classes like `bg-red`, but it has `bg-red-{value}` etc. If you wish to have simple `bg-red`, you need to modify config file depends on your needs

Comment: I just noticed also that unless I change tha class on the .vue file, the browser inspector doesn't load it... I was playing from the browser, toggling the classes and now, by changing them on file, and as you suggested, adding the value, It works...

Comment: Tailwind adds classes on the fly after version 2.2. You may check compiled CSS file, it will not contain all Tailwind classes

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Please turn your comment into an answer if you have an answer.